# java.lang.NullPointerException: when trying to send data via OutputStream in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, arduino

When I try to send a string error shows as:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference

```
(BaseApp)this.getApplicationContext()).my.BTconnect();
((BaseApp)this.getApplicationContext()).my.beginStart();
String s = "w";
try {
  outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it looks like your outputStream is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your outputstream.

```
String file_stream = "C:\Users\s.rodic\eclipse\test.txt";
String s = "w";
try {
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file_stream); //file_stream is your file location
    outputStream.out(s.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i used output stream to send data via bluetooth to my arduino board..so can you help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem in write http or https, if you want that will be connection with your server, try write Only: http

```
String login_url = "http:`stack.com`
```

hope will help you!